# Disabling default S4 class constructors

Tags: r, r-s4

What's the best way to enforce that an S4 object is always created with arguments, meaning that the default constructor can never be called?

Comment: It's not really clear what 'always' means (e.g., it's possible to invoke the first two lines of `new()`, avoiding the `initialize()` method), or what your use case is; users seem quite creative in avoiding conventions or best practices.

Comment: I want to prevent the syntax new('MyClass') from being used when the right syntax is new('MyClass', a='a', b='b')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that creating an explicit 'initialize' method with arguments DOES prevent a new('MyType') call without parameters from being accepted.  It seems that this was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the user doesn't want to use `new()`, but rather a function for which you can specify arguments / hints and provide documentation; ideally the user has no notion that they're using 'S4 classes', just invoking some function that returns an object that they can invoke other functions on. My preferred approach is

```
.A = setClass("A", representation=representation(x="numeric"))
A = function(x=numeric(), ...) {
    ## user-friendly coercion / checks / etc to 'x'
    .A(x=x, ...)
}
## accessors and other methods
```

Export only `A()` in the package NAMESPACE. Since an implicit requirement of S4 classes is that in fact `validObject(new("A"))` evaluates to TRUE (e.g., [from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744214)), it seems difficult to avoid allowing the user to construct the class in this way.

Comment: This seems like an unfortunate kludge in the style of R kludges.  Let's have (poor, hash-based) OO, but let's hide it from the user and have them think there's no typing under the hood.  This is what I was doing, of course.  Isn't there a way to do what I want using 'initialize'?

Comment: @rimorob No, since `new("A")` has to work, `initialize(<instance-of-class-A>)` has to work -- there's no room for passing secret messages.